# Ebean Query logging with Play 2.2.3

Tags: playframework-2.2, ebean

AM using play 2.2.3 and ebean with It. 
I am struggling to get ebean to log the sql query statement.
Can someone please help?

Comment: After play 2.0 the package for ebean has changed.
Kindly add  <logger name="org.avaje.ebean.SQL" level="TRACE"/> to your application.conf 

for 2.0 <logger name="com.jolbox.bonecp" level="TRACE"/> would do. 
Hope this helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After play 2.0 the package for ebean has changed. Kindly add  following line for play 2.2.3

```
<logger name="org.avaje.ebean.SQL" level="TRACE"/>
```

to your application.conf.

for PlayFramework 2.0 and before a

```
<logger name="com.jolbox.bonecp" level="TRACE"/>
```

would do. Hope this helps